# How can I check if Pow is running correctly on my Mac? How can I get it running correctly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack-pow

I'm having difficult seeing `my_proj.dev` from my browser and I'd just like to check if Pow is up and running correctly, or if the issue lies elsewhere.  What is a quick test I can do to see if Pow is installed and running correctly?

1. `launchctl list | grep pow` gives the following:

   ```
   451 0   cx.pow.powd
   ```
2. `ps aux | grep pow` gives the following:

   ```
   jon               451   0.0  0.3  3048228  24300   ??  S    12:38PM   0:00.31 pow
   ```
3. `curl -H host:pow localhost/status.json` gives the following:

   ```
   curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
   ```
4. `curl -H host:pow localhost:3000/status.json` and `curl localhost:3000/status.json` give the following:

   ```
   curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
   ```

UPDATE:

Rebooting my dev machine apparently fixed everything.

Comment: Is there an error message in the browser?  If so, can you post it?

Comment: No error in the browser.

Comment: what version of pow and what operating system?  Yoesemite requires latest version of pow due to firewall changes.

Comment: Yes, Yosemite.  Pow version 0.5.0.

Comment: look in ~/Library/Logs/Pow/  both access.log and apps/*.log to help debug

Answer (score 4):

```
curl -H host:pow localhost/status.json
```

Couple of other endpoints you can hit to pull information out of Pow.  See:

http://pow.cx/manual.html#section_3.2

Comment: That command returns: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused`

Comment: Try `localhost:3000/status.json`

Comment: @JonCrowell do you have Nginx or Apache running?

Comment: @PhilipHallstrom localhost:3000/status.json also returns `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3000: Connection refused` both with and without host:pow.

Answer (score 2):

`ps aux | grep pow`

Should show you at least 2 entries if Pow is running.  The one label simply "pow" is the powder process (the other should be from the grep command).

You could always enter `touch tmp/restart.txt` from the app root.  This will reload the app into pow.

I also recommend installing the [Powder gem](https://github.com/Rodreegez/powder) for managing pow on your apps.

Comment: This shows: `jon   451   0.0  0.3  3048228  24300   ??  S    12:38PM   0:00.31 pow`

Comment: pow is running.  if you look at the columns, the important values are the first, second and last.  first is the user that "owns" the process, the second is the process id (pid) and the last is the executable, or script.

Answer (score 0):

For tmux users, "pow" never installed correctly under tmux.
I read about this here:
https://github.com/basecamp/pow/wiki/Troubleshooting#doesnt-start-cant-connect-to-host

I ended up uninstalling "pow", by running:

```
curl get.pow.cx/uninstall.sh | sh
```

Then in a new Terminal window **without "tmux"**, I installed "pow" again.

```
curl get.pow.cx | sh
```

This time installation worked (the post installation "self-test" passed.)

I later on ran into issues with not having a .rvmrc file (I was using .ruby-version and .ruby-gemset, but somehow "pow" wanted a .rvmrc file).

```
# Change ruby version, gemset, and directory below
cd YOUR_PROJECT_DIRECTORY
echo "rvm ruby-2.2.0@mygemset" >> .rvmrc
```

Finally, after creating the .rvmrc file, I had to create a .powrc file in the project's directory.  This was the contents of the ".powrc"

```
if [ -f "$rvm_path/scripts/rvm" ] && [ -f ".rvmrc" ]; then
    source "$rvm_path/scripts/rvm"
    source ".rvmrc"
fi
```